# Clojure: Filter files with a specific ext but not folders folder

Tags: clojure

I am new to Clojure.
I have a Clojure app, which exposes log directory on http/s.  But unfortunately there are some other files in this same dir.  I need to filter files with .log* extensions only.

We had the following code:

```
(defn get-dir-listing [dir]
  (map #(get-all-attribs %) (fs/list-dir dir)))

(defn get-all-attribs [fpath]
{:type    (if (fs/directory? fpath)
            "Directory"
            "File")
 :name    (.getName fpath)
 :modtime (-> (fs/mod-time fpath)
              time/from-long)
 :size    (-> (fs/size fpath)
              get-size-in-KB)
})
```

I changed it to the following:

```
(defn get-dir-listing [dir]
  (map #(get-dirs-log-files-only %) (fs/list-dir dir)))

(defn get-dirs-log-files-only [fpath]
 (if (and (not (fs/directory? fpath)) (.contains (.getName fpath) ".log"))
    (get-all-attribs fpath)

  (if (fs/directory? fpath)
     (get-all-attribs fpath))))

(defn get-all-attribs [fpath]
{:type    (if (fs/directory? fpath)
            "Directory"
            "File")
 :name    (.getName fpath)
 :modtime (-> (fs/mod-time fpath)
              time/from-long)
 :size    (-> (fs/size fpath)
              get-size-in-KB)
})

;To remove nil
(remove nil? (get-dir-listing "C:\\tmp"))
```

Does anyone have a better way to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

You can move the criteria by which you filter the files into a separate function. This will better convey what you are going to do with the listing. Then, you can use `filter` to apply these criteria.

Also, it is considered a better practice to use Clojure library functions from the relevant namespaces instead of using Java method to work with strings and files (e.g. `clojure.string/includes?` instead of the `String.contains` method).

```
(ns ...
  :require [... [clojure.string :as cs]])

(defn is-log-or-dir? [fpath]
  (or (fs/directory? fpath)
      (cs/includes? (fs/base-name fpath) ".log")))

(defn get-dir-listing [dir]
  (map get-all-attribs (filter is-log-or-dir? dir)))
```